# Why is the space character not displaying in this VisualForce email template?

Tags: email-template

This:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Assignment for {!relatedTo.K__Resource__r.Name} Ends in {!relatedTo.K__ForecastP3EndDate__c - TODAY() -1} Days" recipientType="User" relatedToType="K__ActivityAssignment__c">
```

Gives this:

"Assignment for Joe Smooth Ends in 4 Days" for my email subject

But this:

```
<h2 style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #810541; border-bottom-width: 1px; margin: 10px;">Assignment for {!relatedTo.K__Resource__r.Name} ends <apex:outputText value="{0,date,EEE MMM dd yyyy}">            <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.K__ForecastP3EndDate__c}" /></apex:outputText>.</h2>
```

Gives this in my email body:

"Assignment for Joe Smooth endsMon Apr 14 2014."

Anyone know how I can get a space after the word 'ends' in the second example?

Thanks.

Comment: Its a bodge but a non-breaking space is always output `ends&nbsp;<apex` but then the line won't wrap at that point which may or may not be a problem. Hopefully someone has an explanation and a cleaner fix.

Comment: You could also try a style="padding-left: 10px;" on the outputText - this might work; or wrap the outputText in an outputPanel that has padding-left -- this is the kind of stuff that drives me nuts. If you look at the generated HTML, you might get additional clues on how to style.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is the only way I know of to do it. The reason its happening is because the `<apex:outputText` is like the start of a fresh line of Apex Code. Its not a continuation of the HTML as in the first example where you have the brackets encapsulating output fields.